# Android map - drawing custom markers on permission changes issue (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

I am using Google Map v2 in my application and I'm facing really strange issue.

On the map, I am drawing custom markers - a circle-shaped objects of different colors with the number indicating some kind of information.

The issue is that, for Android 6.0, after taking away permission for location and going back to app, my map markers are drawed with default icon. Granting permission back doesn't change the issue untill I restart the application.

The funny thing is that drawing my custom markers works fine if location permission is disabled at the moment of starting the app. Only if app is working, and then I toggle location permission (turn it off or on), my markers changes to default.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this issue? I want to toggle location permission in settings (which shouldn't have nothing to do with drawing markers on the map) and still draw my custom markers instead of default.

**EDIT:** just to clarify - I AM redrawing markers when I'm going back to the application. The problem is that they are no longer with my custom Icon, but default google marker icon. The code:

```
public void addBay(final String mapMarkerId, final Position position, String status) {
    if(mapService.getMap() != null) {
        final BitmapDescriptor icon = getIconForStatus(status);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Marker newMarker = addMarkerToGoogleMap(position, icon);
                markers.put(mapMarkerId, newMarker);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Marker addMarkerToGoogleMap(Position position, BitmapDescriptor icon) {
    return mapService.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .icon(icon));
}

public BitmapDescriptor getIconForStatus(String status) {

    switch (status) {
        case BayDto.STATUS_FREE:
            return bayStatusFreeIcon;
        case BayDto.STATUS_OCCUPIED:
            return bayStatusOccupiedIcon;
        case BayDto.STATUS_UNKNOWN:
            return bayStatusUnknownIcon;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public void initIcons() {
    bayStatusFreeIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawableUtils.createSingleMarkerFromImage(R.drawable.area_above_9_places));
    bayStatusOccupiedIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawableUtils.createSingleMarkerFromImage(R.drawable.status_occupied));
    bayStatusUnknownIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawableUtils.createSingleMarkerFromImage(R.drawable.status_unknown));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed cashing those icons.

The thing is that on permission change, according to this:
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

> So what will happen if permission is revoked when application is opened? I have already given it a try and found that application's process is suddenly terminated. Everything inside application just simply stopped (since it is already terminated ...). It sounds make sense to me anyway since if OS allows the application to go on its process, it may summon Freddy to my nightmare. I mean even worse nightmare than currently is ...

The thing is that my application didn't crashed or shut down itself. It was still active and I could go back to it. But I think it reloaded itself in some way. So in the activity where I cashed those icons by calling initIcons(), I've decided to put smth like this:

```
public void onCreate(IMapActivityView mapView, boolean isFirstRun) {
    this.view = mapView;

    if(androidBuildSdkReader.getDeviceSdkVersion() >= 23)
        markerProvider.initIcons();
    else
        initIconsIfIsFirstRun(isFirstRun);
}
```

instead of simply:

```
public void onCreate(IMapActivityView mapView, boolean isFirstRun) {
    this.view = mapView;

    initIconsIfIsFirstRun(isFirstRun);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom marker,you copy image(marker image) into drawable folder.

check my code below.

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latitude,longitude).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.markerImage)));//markerImage is my marker image name in darwable folder.
```

Comment: I know how to draw markers. It's not the point. Im passing my custom Icon to the addMarker but it draws default if I toggle permission when app is working

Comment: I've added the code. I'm simply cashing icons so I wouldn't have to create them when drawing a lot of markers (it's good for app performance) and then adding markers to the map.

I really don't think it's the problem with my solution. I'm developing map app for a really really long time and this method was all good until I faced the problem with changing permissions when application is running.

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to app , after allowing permission.
Create object of markers or set color of markers in **onResume()** method.

**onResume()**->called when go back to app, so you need to change in this method.

I hope i will work as you expect.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't precise enough. This is exactly what I am doing. I'm redrawing markers, I'm redrawing them on zoon change, but after I toggle permission when app is working, the drawing result isn't as expected - it's no longer with my custom Icon, but with default android marker Icon.